# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException - when saving Objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, h2

I am facing a *DataIntegrityViolationException* when I want to insert data into my h2 database. There are two entities I am using which are `Team` and `Driver`. The `Team` entity contains a `driverList` which should store `Driver` objects in it.

**Team Class:**

```
@Entity
public class Team {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<Driver> driverList = new ArrayList<>();

/** Constructor **/
public Team(Long id, String name, List<Driver> driverList) {
    super();
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setDriverList(driverList);
}

/** Default - Constructor **/
public Team(){
    super();
    this.name = null;
    this.driverList = null;
}

/** Getters and Setters **/

public List<Driver> getDriverList() {
    return driverList;
}

public void setDriverList(List<Driver> driverList) {
    this.driverList = Ensurer.notNull(driverList, "driverList");
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = Ensurer.notNull(id, "ID");
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = Ensurer.notNull(name,"Name");
}
```

**Driver Class:**

```
@Entity
public class Driver {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private LocalDateTime birthdate;
private String name;
private String nationality;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Team team;

public Driver() {
    super();
    this.id = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.birthdate = null;
    this.nationality = null;
    this.team = null;
}

public Driver(Long id, String name, LocalDateTime birthdate, String nationality, Team team) {
    super();
    this.id = Ensurer.notNull(id,"id");
    this.name = Ensurer.notNull(name,"name");
    this.birthdate = Ensurer.notNull(birthdate,"birthdate");
    this.nationality = Ensurer.notNull(nationality,"nationality");
    this.team = Ensurer.notNull(team,"team");
}
/** Getters and Setters **/

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = Ensurer.notNull(id, "id");
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = Ensurer.notNull(name, "name");
}

public LocalDateTime getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
}

public void setBirthdate(LocalDateTime birthdate) {
    this.birthdate = Ensurer.notNull(birthdate, "birthdate");
}

public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = Ensurer.notNull(nationality, "nationality");
}

public Team getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(Team team) {
    this.team = Ensurer.notNull(team, "team");
}
```

**DriverRepository Interface:**

```
@Repository
public interface DriverRepository extends CrudRepository<Driver, Long> {

}
```

**Create Driver Method in DriverServiceBean:**

```
@Override
public boolean createDriverFrom(String name, LocalDateTime birthDate,
                                String nationality, Team team) {
    Driver Driver = new Driver();
    Driver.setName(name);
    Driver.setBirthdate(birthDate);
    Driver.setNationality(nationality);
    Team t = team;
    Driver.setTeam(t);
    DriverRepository.save(Driver);
    return true;
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKJ82T3X4GWKLQOKPYMTKV7Y7MM: PUBLIC.DRIVER FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TEAM(ID) (737)"; SQL statement:
insert into driver (id, birthdate, name, nationality, team_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-193]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.driverslounge.projectcart.services.DriverServiceImp.createDriverFrom(DriverServiceImp.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.driverslounge.projectcart.presentation.vaadin.window.CreateDriverWindow.initDriverCreation(CreateDriverWindow.java:125) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.driverslounge.projectcart.presentation.vaadin.window.CreateDriverWindow.lambda$new$f5e6da9c$1(CreateDriverWindow.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1015) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:119) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:435) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:407) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379) [vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar:7.7.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2803) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3374) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKJ82T3X4GWKLQOKPYMTKV7Y7MM: PUBLIC.DRIVER FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TEAM(ID) (737)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKJ82T3X4GWKLQOKPYMTKV7Y7MM: PUBLIC.DRIVER FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TEAM(ID) (737)"; SQL statement:
insert into driver (id, birthdate, name, nationality, team_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:372) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:314) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:967) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:985) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:161) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

I've already tried out changing `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` to `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` but this did not seem to help.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Comment: I think you have to save the Team not the Driver (not sure though). Also A convention hint, don't do this: `Driver Driver = new Driver();` use the java naming convention: `Driver driver = new Driver();`

Comment: You are using ElelementCollection incorrectly. ElementCollection should only be used for Embedable types not for entities. Also, did you write the Ensurer class yourself, because then I would see if I could replace it with Guavas `Precondition`. Your actual problem may be that your Team argument is detached, if that is the case you have to merge it into you current persistence context, and it looks like you don't have a persistence context, as it will not be created before you call save.